# Not able to access Jupyter notebook from Anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, permission-denied

I continuously get below error while trying to access to Jupyter notebook through Anaconda.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6vK1.jpg)

What could be the issue?

I have tried to reinstall however no success.

How can I solve it? Could it be related to homebrew?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow it as a guide to posting. Pay especial attention the emphasized bullet point  **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** in the section 'Help others reproduce the problem'. As to your issue, it appears you are mixing and matching installs? I see Homebrew and Anaconda? Did you set up Anaconda recently? Did you first try to install things with Homebrew and not clean up?

Comment: I had Anaconda from the beginning. After installing the homebrew, I started to face this error. I understand your point about asking a good question, however I am not sure about the cause of the problem.

Comment: You had Anaconda from the beginning? Did you uninstall Anaconda and clean out first before installing via homebrew? Or did you not install anything dealing with Python and Jupyter with Homebrew? As for your question, "Could it be related to homebrew?". I think you answered that with your last comment: "I had Anaconda from the beginning. After installing the homebrew, I started to face this error." What was the purpose of adding Homebrew to the mix? I am trying to get at whether you can uninstall that and clean it out and then try getting Anaconda working again?